# UIAlertController - Transitioning to another segue

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to create a `UIAlertController` with two options 'Cancel' and 'Log out'. I want the 'Cancel' button to cancel the alert and the 'Log out' button to perform the segue associated with it, which i have set up in the storyboard.

My code is;

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

@IBAction func SignOutBtn(sender: UIButton) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert",
        message: "Are you sure you want to log out?",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Cancel",
        style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
            print("You selected the Cancel action.")
    }

    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Log out",
        style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
            print("You selected the submit action.")
            self.presentedViewController
    }

    alertController.addAction(submitAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: @Rohit KP I am unable to segue back to my VC if i select "Log out"

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems your'e missing the actions you want to perform inside the blocks.
(also, you may want to dismiss the alert controller, inside the blocks as well.)

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    print("You selected the Cancel action.")
    alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
})
let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Log out", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    print("You selected the submit action.")
    alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        // Perform your custom segue action you need.
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks. How do i perform the segue action programatically? I have used ctrl + dragged it to the VC on the storyboard, how do i call that?

Comment: Thanks. How do i perform the segue action programatically? I have used ctrl + dragged it to the VC on the storyboard, how do i call that? - i tried to add self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)  but whichever button i press it keeps me on the same VC

Comment: see @pbush25 answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up a segue from one view to another, in your button handler for log out then you can call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("storyboadIdentifier")` which will call the `prepareForSegue`method so you can modify or pass info along the segue if need be.

Comment: See my answer below for updated code. The segue still doesn't seem to be called.

Answer (score 0):

@pbush25

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

@IBAction func SignOutBtn(sender: UIButton) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert",
        message: "Are you sure you want to log out?",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("You selected the Cancel action.")
        alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    })
    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Log out", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("You selected the submit action.")
        alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
        })
    })

    alertController.addAction(submitAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```